# session.CustomActionData is empty in repair

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have one custom action that is executed all the time (doesn't have any condition). 
This custom action is "deferred" and get correctly the value on fresh install or upgrade, but in repair mode the value passed is empty.
In setup log the value is shown with correctly, but in custom action the value is ''.
Is correct that in repair the value to be always null?

Comment: The value for the property is given from command line to msi setup.

Comment: What command line are you using?

Comment: msiexec /fpecms .... Property='value'

Comment: did you try to make it public and secure ?

Comment: Public yes, secure no. I will try thanks.